# What are historical reasons why the US people put initial in between their first and last names?

Tags: american-english, names

As far as I know it is not mandatory form of the full name, but many Americans (I reckon it is true for other English speaking nations, but it is much more typical for people in the US) choose to write their names with the middle initial, like «John A. Doe». I can't think of any non-English speaking nation where such full name form would exist. Usually, it is either reduced to «John Doe» (generally, more widespread) or is expanded to «John Anthony Doe». Apparently, Americans are somewhere in between these two limiting cases. Where did this tradition of using initial in stead of the second name come from and when did it become popular amongst Americans?

It is curious that names of many historical figures of the US are usually written without the initial, for example «George Washington» or «Abraham Lincoln».

Comment: In Britain we think of it as a typically American habit too. British authors are usually published under either their first name alone, or just initials.

Comment: However I use my middle initial (although not here, strangely) because my father had the same first initial and -- when I first starting getting my own post regularly as a teenager -- I objected to him opening my post. I'm not sure this is a Use of English thing though: it has nothing to do with language.

Comment: Perhaps boys are more often named after their fathers in the US than they are in the UK and a middle initial is then used to differentiate between them. I don't *think* it happens with girls/mothers. I can't think of a British 'Junior' either. Kings and queens get around this problem with a simple numbering system!

Comment: @KateBunting Oh, yes, of course, you are totally right. I have forgot to mention another obvious logical opportunity that is «J. A. Doe».

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Strictly speaking, it is not just Kings and Queens. I remember seeing something like «John A. Doe III» (I suppose it is pronounced «the third»). Probably, another American «name feature». I don't think I can grasp the meaning of this.

Comment: Because this doesn't have anything to do with the Use of English, but is a cultural thing (or at least, based on an impression of a cultural thing), it's a *better* fit on History.